# Add argument to match 'add(int, ? extends Number)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to populate a list in the **fill()** method below using generics to relax the restrictions of the type parameter but I keep getting the error

> The method add(int, capture#2-of ? extends Number) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (int)

and when I tried fixing it with the compiler, it automatically fills the list with **null**. Please how can I fix this:

```
public static void fill(List<? extends Number> list) {
   for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
      list.add(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That `List<? extends Number> list` parameter allows to read a list of `Number` or its subclasses.
You want to use `List<? super Number> list` parameter for adding elements in the List but you could add only `Number` or superclass instances of that.
So your current implementation could not compile either.

That could work for example :

```
public static void fill(List<? super Integer> list) {
   for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
      list.add(i);
   }
}
```

And you could pass as parameter a variable declared as List of Integer or List of Number or any superclass.

Comment: You are welcome :) Don't hesitate to accept my answer if it suits to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

*is that what You want?*

```
public static void fill( List<Number> list ) {
  for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    list.add( Integer.valueOf( i ) );
  }
}
```

a possible call would be:

```
ArrayList<Number> a = new ArrayList<>();
fill( a );
```

the list can hold `Long`, `Float` and `Double` as well